# C++ Destruir objetos de un arreglo

Tags: c++

Hola tengo un par de dudas

Digamos que tengo este codigo:

```
class alumno
{
    private:
        string nombres;
        char telefono[12];
        int nivel;
    public:
        alumno();
        ~alumno();
}
```

y despues en el main declaro

```
alumno estudiante[10];
```

Mis dudas son:

- Como llamo el destructor para un solo objeto?
- Como destruyo todo el arreglo?
- Si borro un objeto los datos quedan en blanco? o desaparece la
  casilla del objeto? (osea si el tamaño del arreglo es 10, bajara a 9?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### 1. Como llamo el destructor para un solo objeto?

Dentro de un arreglo, puedes hacer `estudiante[3].~alumno( );`

#### 2. Como destruyo todo el arreglo?

Tal y como lo has declarado, el arreglo se *destruye* al salir de la función, de forma automática. Antes de dicha *destrucción*, se invocan, uno a uno, los destructores de los objetos contenidos en el arreglo.

Si quieres poder *destruirlo* cuando te plazca, has de usar memoria dinámica:

```
alumno *estudiante = new alumno[10];
...
delete[] alumno;
```

Si usas esta última fórmula, arreglos *dinámicos*, recuerda que es tu responsabilidad el *destruirlos* haciendo el `delete[]`. El compilador se desentiende totalmente de ellos. Es decir, **no son destruidos ni liberados** al salir de la función.

#### 3. Si borro un objeto los datos quedan en blanco? o desaparece la casilla del objeto? (osea si el tamaño del arreglo es 10, bajara a 9?)

Si las instancias están **dentro de un arreglo**, ni el arreglo ni los datos cambian. Todo queda tal y como esté cuando finalice el **destructor** de la clase implicada.

Si el destructor no hace nada, la memória queda tal y como estuviera. Desde luego, el número de elementos del arreglo **no cambia**.

Piensa que, desde el punto de vista del compilador, un *arreglo* no es mas que **un bloque de memoria**. Una vez *asignado*, no cambia de tamaño (salvo que lo cambiemos nosotros explicitamente).

**Cuidado** con lo que haces. Por lógica, si primero llamas al destructor de un objeto, y luego haces el `delete` del arreglo completo, el destructor **volverá a ser llamado**. Es cosa tuya el comprobar la lógica de tu programa.

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda Dolmenes tenia estas dudas hace tiempo

Comment: @Malthael como te indica eferion en su respuesta, llamar directamente a los destructores es **muy poco habitual**. Será raro que tengas que hacerlo nunca. Pero está bien saber que, como poder, se puede :-)

Comment: @Mathael piensa que C++ es un lenguaje muy complejo con mil recovecos. Si no quieres morir en el intento te sugiero que sigas unas pautas de código limpio sin artificios raros... Y el llamar a los destructores directamente es uno de esos artificios que conviene reservar para situaciones muy muy concretas que no creo que veas en los próximos años

Answer (score 5):

> ¿Cómo llamo el destructor para un solo objeto?

Dentro del vector los objetos están almacenados por valor, luego no es necesario llamar al destructor de un objeto. Entre otras cosas la memoria que ocupa dicho elemento dentro del vector no se va a liberar.

Llamar directamente a los destructores es algo a evitar salvo por motivos muy justificados. Si programas con cierto criterio te darás cuenta de que no es necesario llamarlos de forma explícita.

> ¿Cómo destruyo todo el arreglo?

```
alumno estudiante[10];
```

El arreglo está creado sin usar memoria dinámica, luego no puedes destruirlo manualmente. Cuando la ejecución abandone el ámbito del arreglo el programa llamará de forma automática al destructor de cada objeto del arreglo.

Un caso diferente sería si se hace una reserva de memoria dinámica. En cuyo caso se hace necesario liberar la memoria a mano:

```
alumno* estudiantes = new alumno[10];

delete[] estudiantes;
```

¿Por qué se produce este comportamiento tan dispar?

El arreglo que tú has creado se almacena en la pila del programa o *stack*. La pila está gestionada por el propio programa ya que usa la misma para almacenar los saltos a funciones, luego el programa sabe que debe eliminar las variables.

Cuando usas la memoria dinámica pasas a ser tú el responsable de la gestión de dicha memoria.

> ¿Si borro un objeto los datos quedan en blanco? o desaparece la casilla del objeto? (osea si el tamaño del arreglo es 10, bajara a 9?)

No. Dado que el objeto no usa memoria dinámica no gestiona recursos únicos como ficheros, sockets, etc. **no vas a notar ninguna diferencia**. El destructor no es más que una función más que el compilador sabe que debe llamar ante determinadas circunstancias, como que la variable se sale de ámbito o se realiza una llamada a `delete`.

Comment: gracias Eferion, la parte de la memoria dinamica y estatica siempre se me habia hecho algo muy confuso, y lo de los destructores pensaba usarlos en una opcion de "borrar datos de x estudiante"